# Is there a way to simplify using mutiple values of the same array?

Tags: vb.net

I'm setting up a program to test if a textbox contains certain values and doesn't contain other certain values.

```
For I = 0 To 3

    If textbox(I).Contains("m") And Not textbox(I).Contains(unit(0)) And Not textbox(I).Contains(unit(1)) And Not textbox(I).Contains(unit(2)) Then

        txtResult = textbox(I)

    End If

Next I
```

The code works, but I was wondering if there was a way to simplify

```
textbox(I).Contains(unit(0)) And Not textbox(I).Contains(unit(1)) And Not textbox(I).Contains(unit(2))
```

As in the actual code, there are far more "`unit(I)`" values the program travels through, this has been simplified.

Comment: Put all those values, like "m" and whatever is in unit(x) in an array and nest another for look within your loop

Comment: Are you doing a `String` search or `Control` search? the `textbox(I).Contains("m")` (It doesn't work however because "m" cannot be converted to control) searches for a control not for a string in the `Text` property.  What do you mean by _values?_ Strings?, Controls?

Comment: If that code works then `textbox` must be a `String` array.  How does it make sense to name a `String` array `textbox`?  It's singular for a start, and it doesn't actually describe what the array contains.  Every name should describe what the thing is.  Surely it is actually a `TextBox` array, in which case it should be named `textBoxes`, and you need to use the `Text` property of each element.  Surely `txtResult` is also a `TextBox` and you need to use the `Text` property there too.

Comment: The string stored in textbox is a single character and the name is a work in progress

Comment: Names don't need to be a work in progress.  If a variable is not type `TextBox` then it shouldn't be named `textbox` and not even then.  You know what a variable is for when you declare and, even if it's just temporary, you could make the effort to make your code as clear as possible for us.

Comment: That the `TextBoxes` only contain one character is only tangentially relevant and not relevant to the type of `textbox` at all.  Tell us what type it actually is because either it's a `String` array and the name is downright misleading or it's a `TextBox` array and that code is downright wrong.

Comment: The `Contains` method of a `TextBox` is inherited from `Control` and is for detecting a child control only, so no use for a `TextBox`.  The `Contains` method of a `String` is for detecting the presence of a substring anywhere, which is pointless when the `String` is only one character.

Answer (score 0):

Although the variable names in the question are confusing, it seems that you want something like:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim data = {"am", "b", "cm", "d"}
        Dim unit = {"c", "d", "e"}

        For i = 0 To 3
            Dim ii = i
            If data(ii).Contains("m") AndAlso Not (unit.Any(Function(x) data(ii).Contains(x))) Then
                Console.WriteLine(data(ii))
            End If
        Next

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

> am

The reason for `Dim ii = i` is that [using the iteration variable in a lambda expression may have unexpected results](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/error-messages/using-the-iteration-variable-in-a-lambda-expression-may-have-unexpected-results).